# Inequality for product of symmetric definite matrices of form $ABA$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be positive definite matrices, and suppose that for some $r \geq 1$, $A$ satisfies $I \preceq A \preceq rI$. Can we obtain any non-trivial bound of the form $f(r) B \preceq ABA \preceq g(r)B$
for some real-valued functions $f,g$? If not, is there anything close to this that can be obtained?

Comment: Doubtful. If $n=2$ and $A=\mathrm{diag}(r,1)$ then trace $B^{-1/2}ABAB^{-1/2}$ seems unbounded when $\det B\to 0.$

Comment: All possible $f$s must be trivial (i.e., $f(r)\le0$ for all $r$) and no $g$ exists, because the maximum singular value of $B^{1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ is not bounded above and the minimum singular value is not bounded away from zero.